# discord.py - How to reset the cooldown of a command for a specific user?

Tags: python, discord, python-3.7, discord.py

I have two commands in my bot that use a cooldown : "suggest" and "repentir".
I have made another command to reset the cooldown for an user, here is the code of that command :

```
@client.command()
@commands.check(is_owner)
async def reset(ctx, user:discord.Member):
    repentir.reset_cooldown(ctx)
    suggest.reset_cooldown(ctx)
    await ctx.send("Le cooldown pour <@{}> a bien été réinitialisé !".format(ctx.author.id))
```

I have already tried to put `user` inside of the `reset_cooldown()` fonctions, but this command takes a `Context` argument, and `user` is `Member` type, so it raises an error...
Is there any way to reset the cooldown for a specific user ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that there's a command available to reset the cooldown just for a singular specified user.

If you aren't already, I'd suggest using the command decorator with the user variation of BucketType to make sure that cooldowns are user specific. `@commands.cooldown(rate, per, commands.BucketType.user)`. [Docs for cooldown decorator](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html)

Comment: Yeah, the cooldowns are already user specifics, but sometimes I need to reset the cooldown for one of my friends... According to the documentation, `reset_cooldown` takes a `Context` argument...

Comment: You can use this, not sure how relevant it is anymore but this is some of my old code.
`bot.get_command("Command name here").reset_cooldown(ctx)`

Comment: Yeah, I already know how to reset the cooldown, but i want to do it for a specific user....

Comment: You could create a custom cooldown using a list/set and just have a check to see if someone is in the list before running the command. Then removing a specific user from that list would be pretty easy.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a function to check which members you want to reset the cooldown and another function "before_invoke" to before the command runs check the first function, and, if it is true, resets the cooldown

```
def check_if_it_is_me(ctx):
    return ctx.message.author.id == 759027058613026827


class ImaCog(commands.Cog, name='Imagens'):
    """Gifs e imagens para você se divertir"""

    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

    async def cog_before_invoke(self, ctx: commands.Context):
        if check_if_it_is_me(ctx):
            return ctx.command.reset_cooldown(ctx)

    @commands.command(brief='Manda uma piscadinha',
                      help='Use o comando para ver uma pisacadinha aleatória de algum anime. Você pode enviar a '
                           'piscadinha para alguem marcando a pessoa no comando')
    @commands.cooldown(1, 5, commands.BucketType.user)
    async def pisque(self, ctx, quem: discord.Member = None):
        gif = await buscar('animu', 'wink')
        await ctx.send(ctx.author.mention,
                       embed=gera_embed(ctx=ctx, link=gif, membro=quem,
                                        acao_s='piscou', acao_c='mandou uma piscada para'))
```

all commands in this cog have an "@ commands.cooldown (1, 5, commands.BucketType.user)" that limits the use of commands once every 5 seconds per user. But before each cog command, the "async def cog_before_invoke" is called, which in turn calls the "check_if_it_is_me" function, which returns true if the command's author is me, and back to the "async def cog_before_invoke" function which resets the cooldown if the "check_if_it_is_me" function be true. If the "check_if_it_is_me" function is false (it is not me using the command), the "cog_before_invoke" function will not reset the cooldown,  and the author of the command will have to wait for the cooldown normally.

You can add more parameters for the "check_if_it_is_me" function, such as a list of members who will not have to wait for the cooldown or a time when the cooldown will have no effect, but that is up to you

I hope it was clear and good luck